# Is a top heat gas grill, capable of 800°C / 1500°F perfect for pizza and sous vide steak?

Tags: pizza, steak, searing, grill

I am talking about something like this:

[image]

The biggest problem with home made pizza seems to be the lack of temperature, which dries out the dough. Professional pizza makers bake a pizza for under 2 minutes at about 400-450°C / 800-900°F.

I also appreciate this machine's capability to sear a *sous vide* steak, without creating a gradient.

Basically, this looks like exactly what I am looking for, a steak / pizza machine, which can do grilling as well.

At first I wanted to get a Weber gas grill, but the problem is the low maximum temperature.

One downside of this machine is that it doesn't heat evenly at all. But I think I could get around that by turning the pizza.

Does this machine have any disadvantages compared to similar solutions, which are produced for home made pizza specifically?

The temperature checks out, but is it missing something critical? And also, would it actually produce crust without cooking the inside, similar to a torch, but hopefully a lot quicker?

If a grill existed, which could cover these two things (steak searing after *sous vide* and proper pizza) I would actually prefer something like a Weber gas grill. But my understanding is, that these have trouble achieving anything above 350°C / 700°F.

Comment: The problem with this for pizza is the top-heating feature.  Best for Neapolitan pizza is a very hot surface that quickly cooks the crust, along with a very high ambient temperature that cooks the top.

Comment: I think the hot surface won't be a problem, since I can use a steel / stone in it. So the problem is basically uneven heat right? Any way to get around that somehow? Maybe use a cover over the pizza or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

No, at least for pizza.

Pizza needs to be cooked as fast as possible from all sides so that the crust is cooked and the topping are not over-cooked/burned.

In the case of a top-heat oven, you will over-cook/burn the topping before the crust is cooked.

i think it would be OK for broiling the steaks after vacuum cooking them.

Comment: Agree completely, but I'll quibble with the phrase "vacuum cooking."  I think you mean sous vide or low temperature cooking.  While "sous vide" does translate to "under vacuum," the method is easily accomplished without vacuum, such as by using a ziploc bag.

Comment: Even if I use a well preheated stone on the bottom?

Comment: Given the choice between gas grill and this thing, which would you prefer for my needs? Obviously none of the options are perfect.

Comment: @user1721135 I would say that this is not suited for pizza, and you could do just fine for steak with a stove top or BBQ grill.  This would not give you any major advantage.  How hot does your oven get?  I do pizza just fine (yes a pizza oven would be better) in my oven with a pizza steel.

Comment: 240 C. It works but it's not great.